# Selecting elements that are dynamically created and that listen to two or more events

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In my code that I'm writing I have a dynamically created div with an input box and a button. When their events occurs they have similar function to do, but there are small differences. For example if the button was clicked find the *siblings* value which is the inputs value and remove the div and replace the div that includes a new input an a button, but if the user pressed enter to find `$(this).val()` and do the same thing to the div, so the functions are similar. I want to combine these event handlers to the proper event that occur.

I want to do something like this:

`$("body").on('click keypress' ,'button input', function(e){`

I need the second parameter in the `on()` because the button and input are created dynamically

If I do something like below the event handlers don't get attached to the newly created elements, I think.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0

    function giveNew(el, i) {
        $(el).remove()
        $("body").append("<button class='go" + " " + i + "' >Go</button>")
    }

    $("body button, body input").on('click keypress', function(e) {
        counter++;
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (target.is('button')) {
            for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
                giveNew(this, i)
            }

            console.log($(this).attr("class"))
        } else if (target.is('input')) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                alert("input");
            }

        }
    })

});
```

html:

```
<input class = "input"> <button class="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add comma between the elements to bind events on [multiple](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) elements

```
$("body").on('click keypress' ,'button, input', function(e) {
```

I'd recommend you to add a class to all the target elements and use that class to bind event.

Javascript:

```
$(document.body).on('click keypress', '.myClass', function(e) {
```

Html:

```
<input class ="input myClass" />
<button class="go myClass">Go</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that comma was the missing piece. I'm curious to know why you would recommend to add the class. remind me. I was going to add a class in my code like `.input` or `.button` and not use the html element. why is it better select to select classes and not the element?

Comment: @user2537537 Because there will be 100 `input` and `button`, however only few of interest. Using `common class` will only select the elements of interests. Also, `class` selector is faster than `element` selector.